# Set environment variable when generating dockerfile within gradle?

Tags: docker, gradle

I am generating my dockerfile in gradle before I do the docker build command. I know you normally set an environment variable when writing your own dockerfile, you would do it like this:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /path/to/java
```

But when you try to get gradle to create the dockerfile, that syntax doesn't work. Here is my current task in gradle.build :

```
task createDockerFile(type: Dockerfile) {
    destFile = project.file('build/docker/Dockerfile')
    from 'openjdk:10-jdk-slim'
    addFile "./build/libs/MyRestAPI-${project.version}-SNAPSHOT.jar", "MyRestAPI.jar"
    runCommand 'sh -c \'touch /MyRestAPI.jar\''
    exposePort 9080
    entryPoint 'java', '-jar', '/MyRestAPI.jar'
    ENV 'JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk10'
}
```

When I run this using ./gradlew createDockerFile, I get this error :

```
unexpected token: JAVA_HOME @ line 54, column 9.
         ENV 'JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk10'
             ^
```

Comment: I’d be surprised if you had to manually set `$JAVA_HOME` at all running on top of an image with a JVM preinstalled.

Comment: See - I thought that... but when I have my jenkins file do ./gradlew createDockerFile, I get the no JAVA_HOME error. :(

Comment: @DavidMaze I am facing a similar problem, but in my case I need to set the AWS access keys as env variables and in the gradle task I am adding - setEnvironment('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',System.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'))
    setEnvironment('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',System.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))                                                                                                  Inside the task, but still when starting the container, i keep getting no credentials found exception, is this the proper way to declare env varibales for the container?